# Show div #id on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

When a div is clicked, I want different div to appear.

Thus, when '#music' is clicked, I want '#musicinfo' to appear.

Here is the css:

```
#music {
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-right:80px;
    font-family: "p22-underground",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:13pt;

    }

#musicinfo {
    width:380px;
    margin:25px;
    font-family: "p22-underground",sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:13pt;
    line-height:1.1;
    display:none;

}
```

and jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#music").click(function () {
$("#musicinfo").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

Any help whatsoever would be great :)

Comment: And if you wrap that into a `$(document).ready()` method, then it'll work. What's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the event-handlers are being bound before the elements are present in the DOM, if you wrap the jQuery inside of a `$(document).ready()` then it should work perfectly well:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").show("slow");
        });

    });
```

An alternative is to place the `<script></script>` at the foot of the page, so it's encountered after the DOM has been loaded and ready.

To make the `div` hide again, once the `#music` element is clicked, simply use `toggle()`:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").toggle();
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UpX3L/).

And for fading:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UpX3L/1/).

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Is there a way I can make it hide, when clicked again?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `jQuery toggle` to show and hide the div. The script will be like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("#music").click(function () {
        jQuery("#musicinfo").toggle("slow");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is simple way to Display Div using:-**

```
$("#musicinfo").show();  //or
$("#musicinfo").css({'display':'block'});  //or
$("#musicinfo").toggle("slow");   //or
$("#musicinfo").fadeToggle();    //or
```