# When Click on button load the pages with anaimation

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

am struggling from last 2 days. when i click on button1 load the page in class called "loadpage" with animation from left. same like button2 also but the animation start from right. and onclick button 3 load page 3 from center. Please help on this.

```
      <div id="main">    
        <div class="home">
         <button>1</button>
         <button>2</button>
         <button>3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="loadpage"></div>

     </div>

     <div id="page1"></div>
     <div id="page2"></div>
     <div id="page3"></div>
```

Comment: Show us your jQuery code so far, and make a JSFiddle

Comment: don't have any jQuery code. Please help me Tom. am new to jQuery.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for ideas. People here won't write code from scratch for you, but they will help you if you show you have made a good attempt. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237163/show-div-id-on-click-with-jquery) has a demo of how to show a div on click, you can combine that with some animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you need but i think u need like this. . .

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
           $('#yourpage1id').hide();
           $('#yourpage2id').hide();
           $('#yourpage3id').hide();
      $('#yourbutton1id').click(function (){
           $('#yourpage1id').show();
      });
      $('#yourbutton2id').click(function (){
           $('#yourpage2id').show();
      });
      $('#yourbutton3id').click(function (){
           $('#yourpage3id').show();
      });
 });
```