# how to hide cc , bcc in mail box form initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I have developed a mail box form where i want to hide cc , bcc option initially. cc, bcc will when i click on their option.
I am not able to do this.

```html
<form class="inbox-compose form-horizontal" id="fileupload" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="inbox-compose-btn">
        <button class="btn green">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Send</button>
        <button class="btn default inbox-discard-btn">Discard</button>
        <button class="btn default">Draft</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group mail-to">
        <label class="control-label">To:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-to">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to">
            <span class="inbox-cc-bcc">
                <span class="inbox-cc"> Cc </span>
                <span class="inbox-bcc"> Bcc </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group input-cc display-hide">
        
        <label class="control-label">Cc:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-cc">
            <input type="text" name="cc" class="form-control"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group input-bcc display-hide">
        
        <label class="control-label">Bcc:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-bcc">
            <input type="text" name="bcc" class="form-control"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Subject:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group">
        <textarea class="inbox-editor inbox-wysihtml5 form-control" name="message" rows="12"></textarea>
```

Please help me to make my form better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show div #id on click with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237163/show-div-id-on-click-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Initially hide the div like:

```
<span class="inbox-cc-bcc" style="display:none;">
    <span class="inbox-cc"> Cc </span>
    <span class="inbox-bcc"> Bcc </span>
</span>
```

and show it by adding an event listener on `cc, bcc button` using jquery `show()` method

Comment: could you please help me with some working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hide` class to hide sections that you would like to hide initially.

**HTML**

```
<form class="inbox-compose form-horizontal" id="fileupload" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="inbox-compose-btn">
        <button class="btn green">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Send</button>
        <button class="btn default inbox-discard-btn">Discard</button>
        <button class="btn default">Draft</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group mail-to">
        <label class="control-label">To:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-to">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to">
            <span class="inbox-cc-bcc">
              <span class="inbox-cc" style="cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;"> Cc </span>
                <span class="inbox-bcc" style="cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;"> Bcc </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divCC" class="inbox-form-group input-cc display-hide hide">

        <label class="control-label">Cc:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-cc">
            <input type="text" name="cc" class="form-control"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divBCC" class="inbox-form-group input-bcc display-hide hide">

        <label class="control-label">Bcc:</label>
        <div class="controls controls-bcc">
            <input type="text" name="bcc" class="form-control"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Subject:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inbox-form-group">
    <textarea class="inbox-editor inbox-wysihtml5 form-control" name="message" rows="12"></textarea></div>


    <div id="push"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('.inbox-bcc').click(function(){
     console.log('bcc');
     $('#divBCC').toggleClass('hide');
 });
});
```

**Here is a working fiddle:** http://www.codeply.com/go/iPH6UVoHkc

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't put your answer on an external site but include it in your post.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Noted and Corrected!.

Comment: @DavidR CC , BCC options are not working. when i click on cc , bcc option their option has to appear.