# What's the best solution to hide/show these rows in a table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, show-hide

Originally I thought I wanted to implement collapsible rows into my table but I figured that won't really work since the spacing and margins... so I thought about it and realized I all really want to do is hide and show the information on click.

Here is an example of the actual code I'm using:

```css
.isaaccrm {
    
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    }

    .zoho {
    
    height: 50px;
    width: 115px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    
    }

    .salesforce {
    
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .infusionsoft {
    
    height: 25px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    }

    .sugarcrm {
    
    height: 60px;
    width: 90px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 55px;
    float: right;
    }

    .comparisons {
    
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    /* Make the comparison font into Lato*/
    
    }

    .center {
    
    text-align:center;
    
    }
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><img class="isaaccrm" src="http://isaacintelligence.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ISAAC-logo-cropped.png"/></th>
            <th><img class="zoho" src="http://i.imgur.com/R8vz9iG.png"/></th>
            <th><img class="salesforce" src="http://i.imgur.com/UhUHB4P.png"/></th>
            <th><img class="infusionsoft" src="http://i.imgur.com/iGzEnUr.png"/> </th>
            <th><img class="sugarcrm" src="http://i.imgur.com/weilyrP.png"/></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th> <p class="comparisons">Operating Systems</p>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
                <td class="center">Web</td>
            </th>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```

And this is what it looks like on my website:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYiQk.png]

That Operating Systems is a row, and I just want to be able to sort of hide the data inside while keeping the name on the left visible, and then on click, show that information (and the cycle goes on). When I say "hide" that data, I mean I want the rows to sort of shrink as if they are being collapsed, and then expand and show the data when clicked.

Is there a function for this sort of thing?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: `.slideUp()`/`.slideDown()`.   Unfortunately doesn't work well with table rows/cells, but you can wrap your content inside a div and slide the divs.  Alternatively, use divs for layout rather than a table then you wont have that issue.

Comment: What have you tried to do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237163/show-div-id-on-click-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You Could try to hide the .center then show them on .comparisons click
So, in CSS

```
.center{display:none;}
```

Then in JS

```
$('.comparisons').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  $('.center').toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps, (not explaining a lot, on mobile) SYA
And this is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q866wkht/)