# Trigger action on checking URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating links to sections on the same page in HTML. By default they are not visible **display : none**. I want when my user clicks on the link (URL) which included id so it should set `display : block`. For example **opening** is the id when **window.location.href** includes `#opening` so content should be visible. User can simply hit mydomain#opening in the browser without clicking `<a>` or `#id`.

**HTML**

```
<p id="opening">Hyperlinks are utilized by a web browser to move from one page to another...</p>
<p>My Name is XYZ...</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#opening {display : none;}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show div #id on click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237163/show-div-id-on-click-with-jquery)

Comment: No. User can simply hit mydomain#opening in the browser without clicking <a> or #id.

Comment: It can be hard to come up with the right search terms, but please do try searching before posting a new question.  There are *many* examples here on SO showing many variations on what you want to do, eg  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<a href="#opening" onclick="$('#opening').css({display: 'block'})" >Take me to the opening paragraph.</a>
```

OR

```
$("a").click(function() { 
   var href =  $(this).attr("href"); 
   href = href.replace("#",""); 
   $("#"+href).css("display","block"); 
})
```

On window load :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
 if (hash) {
  $("#"+hash).css("display","block"); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this work when user simply hits mydomain#opening in the browser without clicking <a>

Comment: no you have to call in window.load function for that

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari if this answers helped  you then please up-vote my answer thanks

Comment: I'm beginner. Can you please update answer based on that?

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari  check i haved updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. It is not working. I guess it has an extra }. I corrected it but still not working

Comment: Does it need to wrap it in settimeout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231358/discussion-between-toxy-and-ujjawal-bhandari).